# Total Item SSAS as calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've got an analysis cube with the dimensions Order, Account and Time (there are some more, but not important for the question. A result will look like this:

```
                Jun 13    Jul 13 ...
Order A  
  Account A       10        15       
  Account B       15        16
  ...

Order B
  Account A       10        12
  Account B       12        15
  ...

...
```

What I try to create is a SUM Item base on the Current selection (Order A+Order B):

```
                Jun 13    Jul 13 ...
Order A  
  Account A       10        15       
  Account B       15        16
  ...

Order B
  Account A       10        12
  Account B       12        15
  ...

...

Complete
  Account A       20        27
  Account B       27        31
```

I'm not sure if this is possible to get from SSAS by creating a calculated member. Could anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you use tabular model;
Select grid view and your table you will see on last column "add column" write there you name exp:"complate" and select it and write formula bar this :

=DimensionName[Order A]+DimensionName[Order B]

Answer (score 0):

No need for a calculated member, this is already available in your cube: Just use the `All` member! Assuming the hierarchy you are interested in is `[Order].[Order]`, then you can reference the `All` member in MDX as `[Order].[Order].[All]` or `[Order].[Order].&[All]`.